# sqlite or Sequlize seems to have broken my app

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a node js app that doesn't work since I installed packages sqlight or sequlize.

This is my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('hello world');
});
```

I put `runjs index.js` in my terminal, response: Starting: index.js, theese are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook-token": "^3.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.23.3",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.4"
  }
```

Visiting localhost:3000 renders the response

```
This site can’t be reached – ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a listener method as well.

This should work:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not listening on port 3000.

```
app.listen(3000)
```